# Replacement of certain percentage of vector in r

Tags: r

I need an R-code to delete certain percentage of numbers in a vector and replace the deleted numbers with another number....
e.g
consider this random number,
x=rnorm(100,1,3)
I want to delete 25% of the generated numbers and replace the deleted numbers by deleted number+29

Please, I need somebody to help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: How do you select this 25%? Randomly? If so, does each element have the same chance of being deleted?

Comment: Yes.. the 25% may be randomly or the first 25% of the elements or the last 25% of the elements. Not necessarily same chance of being selected. The most important thing is that 25% of the elements deleted and these deleted elements replaced by deleted element+29

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
x[seq_len(length(x)*0.25)] <- 29
```

This will replace in front of x. You can randomize the result using `sample(x)`.

Another option is to use x as a base for generation :

```
c(sample(x,size = length(x)*0.75) ,rep(29, length(x)*0.25))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what I want is that the deleted numbers should be replaced by deleted number+29 i.e deleted number plus 29

Comment: You get that for example by `x[seq_len(length(x)*0.25)] <- 29 + x[seq_len(length(x)*0.25)]`.

Comment: Thanks jhin... when I run the code x[seq_len(length(x)*0.25)] <- 29 + x[seq_len(length(x)*0.25)], I discovered that the length of the new vector is now 25 instead of 100. That is it has lost 75 observations completely.