# Replacement of certain percentage of element in vector in r

Tags: r

Please, I want to replace 25% of deleted element in the vector below by maximum of the numbers+550*deleted element
i.e
x=rnorm(100,1,4)
I want to delete 25% of elements in x
I want to replace each of the deleted element of x with 
'maximum of x + 550*deleted elements'

Thanks

Comment: Having difficulty parsing your request. Learn to use punctuation to separate your sentences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379014/replacement-of-certain-percentage-of-vector-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% on exactly what you are asking but hopefully this is what you were after.

```
n = 100 # size of x
x = rnorm(n,1,4)
```

Get positions of 25% of elements in x randomly

```
rep = sample(x = 1:n, size = 0.25*n, replace = FALSE)
```

Update the elements in x selected for replacement

```
x[rep] = max(x) + 550*x[rep]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code your supplied only returned 25 elements instead of 100. Please can you review the code for proper correction? I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I discovered that your code worked perfectly for what I needed it for. Thank you so much I greatly appreciate it. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Glad I could help Sunny